# Large table : fill missing values

Tags: algorithm, bigdata, missing-data

I have a large table of numeric values (up to 400k lines and 3 to 7 columns). I don't know the table pattern and data nature in advance (depends on which data file is opened in my program).

I need to deal with missing data. I would like to fill them with calculated values (depending on others points). I've read a lot of things on the internet about that but I'm quite a beginer.

Does someone know a simple and efficient way to fill missing values on large tables?

I work with JavaScript.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

An example added

```
a, b, c, d, e, f
83.619147,-7.377613,15.915,0.70899963,0.078,0.34700012
83.586208,-7.376209,14.495,0.32199955,0.031,0.058000565
83.611485,-7.37933,16.142,0.60599995,0.087,0.08100033
83.667129,-7.378004,16.212,0.5710001,0.093,0.017999649
```

But as I said, the schemas of the tables I process are not fixed. I don't know in advance the nature of the table/data.

Comment: can you show an example of your problem ? why are you need to add the missing data ? what is your calculation ?

Comment: added ; I need the data for plots/graph. And I've been asked not to delete lines where there are missing values.

Comment: Read about regression and extrapolation. Since it is not clearly defined how to generate missing data, I can only give you a general area to explore various different methods.

Comment: I don't see any missing values in the example you gave.